# Get a list of categories Wp API

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, wp-api

Is there a way to get a list of categories (just the name and maybe date) from WP API?  I don't want to see the posts within the category, just the categories.

Comment: try this [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)

Comment: I did.  It only explains how to get a list of posts within a category, but does not give any category data.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all registered taxonomies :

```
http://domain.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/
```

Note that custom taxonomies needs to be enabled in rest, more info here:
http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/